# Ant buid clears eclipse console - how to stop?

Tags: eclipse, ant, console

whenever I do an ant build, my console results (Errors, warnings etc.) are deleted and it always Shows 
"BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: xxx milliseconds"

how can I prevent the ant file from overwriting my actual console Output?

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

open "External Tools Configuration" (in my eclipse-ui its next to the green run button in the menu bar) -> open your ant runconfig -> go to "common" -> disable "Allocate console (necessary for input)"

this should prevent the overwriting of the console.

in my eclipse version (eclipse mars rc2) it leads to the situation that the current console is closed, but no ant console opens....i think this behaviour is not intended (maybe an eclipse bug). so its the half way to a solution: no ant output but still a deleted console output.

Maybe it works for your eclipse version

greetings

Comment: thanks Matthias, that solved it right the way I wanted!